# solr index multiple urls to the same page

Tags: solr, search-engine, nutch

I'm using Apache Nutch and Solr to build my search engine.
I found in the result that there is multiple urls that point to the same page, these urls indexed in solr as different result

EX:

http://www.adab.com/modules.php?name=Sh3er&doWhat=shqas&qid=83067&r=&rc=13
http://www.adab.com/modules.php?name=Sh3er&doWhat=shqas&qid=83067&r=&rc=15

How to avoid this duplication in my search engine?

Comment: What's actually the problem? Multiple URLs point to the same page, is it a problem?

Comment: yes it is, when showing the result of a search word, multiple results will appear that point to the same page and same content, in order to optimize my search engine's result, I have to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

you could set up [deduplication](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/De-Duplication) so that duplicates are discarded.